# How to call payable methods with the polkadot API?

Tags: polkadot, ink, smart-contract, rust, api

I want to call a payable method using the polkadot API.

if the method would not be payable it would look like this:

```
const { gasRequired, storageDeposit, result, output } = await contract.query
            .method(
                fromAccount,
                {
                    gasLimit,
                    storageDepositLimit
                },
                toAccount,
                input,
                input2
            )
```

But how could I transfer a certain amount of native chain tokens when calling this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `{ value: valueToBeSent }` as the last argument in the `method`

```
.method( arg1, arg2, { value: valueToBeSent })
```

This is how it works for `tx` call:

```
await contract.connect(owner).tx.createCollection(collectionMetadata, collectionMax, collectionSymbol, { value: reserveValue });
```

Check also if your `query` call method is payable. Most likely there is no charge for query.